# How to autodetect the value from array and set the bgcolor from another array

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I have two Arrays called `arr_o` and `arr_t`

```
x = document.getElementsByClassName("div");     //simple div width and height is 100px and 100px
for (var i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++ ){
   var arr_o = [one,two,three];                //classes name
   for (var j = 0 ; j < arr_o.length ; j++ ){
       var arr_t = ["blue","green","red"];     // background color value
       for (var l = 0 ; l < arr_t.length ; l++ ){
            if(x[i].classname === arr_o[j] ){
             x[i].style.backgroundColor = arr_t[l];
            }
       }
   }
}
```

so I want to make a div which autodetect the class name and set the background color respectively from both array

**example**

if the class is `one` then div background will be `"blue"`

if the class is `two` then div background will be `"green"`

if the class is `three` then div background will be `"red"`

*should I use the forEach loop instead what are the other ways for it ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object and the class name as key, with [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName).

```
var colors = {
    one: 'blue',
    two: 'green',
    three: 'red'
};

x = document.getElementsByTagName("div");     //simple div width and height is 100px and 100px
for (var i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++ ){
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[x[i].classname];
}
```

Comment: `getElementById` will return `DOM-object` which does not have `length` property hence `for-loop` will never iterate.. Also typo in `getElementsById`, it is singular...

Comment: @Rayon, right, i think, op needs  `getElementsByName`.

Comment: Yeah! My guess is he is looking for [__`getElementsByTagName`__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)

Comment: @Rayon, that is better :)

Comment: @NinaScholz I dont know op though , can you give a codepen of this a small

Answer (score 0):

Use a array mapping.

```
var map = new array();
map["one"] = "blue";
map["two"] = "green";
map["three"] = "red";

x = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (var i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++ ){
   x[i].style.backgroundColor = map[x[i].classname];

}
```